# What is the best way to write data of AnyContent type in Phantom for Scala?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

For example, I have some

```
data: AnyContent
```

I don't know which content it will be.

But I assume that BlobColumn will be good to write that data.

But how should I convert it so that cassandra will save and get this record?

Answer (score 0):

As i understood is AnyContent only a datatype for dynamic content parsing based on the response header. I think it's not really good idea to write this response in one column. Why you doesn't map the response against an class? But if you really want this in one column you can parse it simply asString. Can you write a bit more about you specific problem? Maybe a other solution is better.